# How to post embedded links into a Draft.js rich text editor?

Tags: javascript, draftjs

**The problem**:

- I want users of my website to be able to post a Google Forms link inside the Draft js text editor and the actual Google Form shows up, just like a YouTube video would on certain websites like Facebook

**What I have tried**:

- I cannot find any documentation on implementing this

**Code**:

- I just have the default Draft js rich text editor at the moment. It lets users use bold, italics, etc

Comment: I think you would have to implement it yourself or get it from plugin like this one. https://github.com/jimmycodesocial/draft-js-iframely-plugin

Comment: yes, you need to implement it yourself. you need to create your own atomic block and render a react component. you may can use an existing component like this. haven't tested it : https://github.com/jnsjknn/react-google-forms